# Is my User is using an RTL language?

Tags: visualforce, language

When a user's language is set to an RTL language (like Hebrew for example) - we see the `dir=rtl` set on the  tag for a VF page. In this situation we'd also like to load a different CSS file specifically for rtl styles. Is there a way to use the $User variable or some other variable available in the Visual Force page to be able to detect if the user is using an rtl language?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in VF but you can try `system.debug(userinfo.getlanguage()+'---------'+userinfo.getlocale());
 and based on the value you can set parameter.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000205580&language=en_US) article it is said that:

> The orientation of the text is determined by the user language. If you are salesforce in a left-to-right language (i.e English), all text will be left-to-right oriented. If you change your user language to a right-to-left language (i.e Hebrew), that text will also follow this orientation.

Based on this we can conclude that we could create a function in our controller that will check the language and determine if it is right-to-left. Something like this:

```
public class MyController {

    public Boolean isLanguageRTL {get; set;}

    public MyController(){
         this.isLanguageRTL = checkIsLanguageRTL(UserInfo.getLanguage());
    }

    public Boolean checkIsLanguageRTL(String language){
        if(language == 'iw' ||
          language == 'ar' ||
          language == 'ur'){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

You can then use the `isLanguageRTL` variable to load the required CSS in your Visualforce page.

Comment: Works like a dream - thanks @smukov. For reference here's how I used it in my page to change the CSS:
`<apex:stylesheet value="{!IF(isLanguageRTL, URLFOR($Resource.slds, '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.rtl.min.css'), URLFOR($Resource.slds, '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.min.css'))}"/>`